# unorderable types: NoneType() > str()

Tags: python

I've never used Python before and I am a total n00b, but I'm trying to execute a script in py on Windows, using the Boto library and Python 3.*.
This is the part of the script generating the error:

```
latest_date = None
    for key in bucket.list(prefix="meta-review/"):
        done_file_match = re.match("^meta-review/([^/]+)/done$", key.key)
        if done_file_match:
            date = done_file_match.group(1)
            latest_date = max(date, latest_date)

    assert latest_date is not None, "No complete dump folder found!"
```

but when I execute the script using the command line I get this error message as output:

```
INFO:root:Connecting to Amazon S3
INFO:root:Looking for latest complete dump
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "*******.py", line 78, in <module>
    download_latest(aws_access_key, aws_secret_key, args.dest_folder)
  File "*******.py", line 41, in download_latest
    latest_date = max(date, latest_date)
TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() > str()
```

(Obviously asterisks are for privacy).
Can anyone tell me where can I find a solution?
I noted that there are similar error already reported, but I'm not understanding what to change.

Any ideas?

Comment: You cannot compare a `None` to a `str`. `max()` performs a comparison. That's all.

Comment: BTW, what can be private about a file name?

Comment: that is a misuse of `assert`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initially `latest_date` is `None`, so as others mentioned `max` can't work.

So, change

```
latest_date = max(date, latest_date)
```

into

```
latest_date = date if latest_date is None else max(date, latest_date)
```

Do note the comparison is between strings so those strings had better be in a properly comparable date format, e.g `'20141223`' or the like.

Comment: I've done in this way and now it works! Thank you Alex!

Answer (score 2):

With Python2, it was possible to compare strings with `None`, but this was changed in Python3 (see [What’s New In Python 3.0: Ordering Comparisons](https://docs.python.org/release/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#ordering-comparisons) for details).

The simplest way to fix your issue is to initialize `latest_date` to an empty string (which will always compare as less than any non-empty string), and then do a length test in your assert statement:

```
latest_date = ""
...

        latest_date = max(date, latest_date)

assert len(latest_date), "No complete dump folder found!"
```

Comment: That works too, and it may read better (though it's less explicit) than my suggested `if/else` expression.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking max() to compare two different types (None and a string)